# Replace value per row with value in first column

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe

My question is very simple. I have a data frame with various numbers in each row, more than 100 columns. First column is always a non zero number. What I want to do is replace each nonzero number in each row (excluding the first column) with the first number in the row (the value of the first column)

I would think in the lines of an ifelse and a for loop that iterates through rows but there must be a simpler vectorised way to do it...

Comment: Post an example suitable for testing and demonstration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach is to use `sapply`, which is more efficient than looping. Assuming your data is in a data frame `df`:

```
df[,-1] <- sapply(df[,-1], function(x) {ind <- which(x!=0); x[ind] = df[ind,1]; return(x)})
```

Here, we are applying the `function` over each and all columns of `df` except for the first column. In the `function`, `x` is each of these columns in turn:

1. First find the row indices of the column that are zeroes using `which`.
2. Set these rows in `x` to the corresponding values in the rows of the first column of `df`.
3. Returns the column

Note that the operations in the function are all "vectorized" over the column. That is, no looping over the rows of the column. The result from `sapply` is a matrix of the processed columns, which replaces all columns of `df` that are not the first column.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega) for an excellent review of the `*apply` family of functions.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. Just out of curiosity, couldn't we use apply to do the same over each row instead of each column?

Comment: `apply` is for applying a function across some dimension of an array. See [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega) for a good review of the `*apply` family of functions.

Comment: Seems like this doesn't do what I wanted but it's just a case of changing which==0 to which!=0. Remember I want to change all **nonzeros** to the first number of each row. Posting from my iPad so didn't try it yet

Answer (score 1):

Since you're data is not that big, I suggest you use a simple loop

```
for (i in 1:nrow(mydata))
{
 for (j in 2:ncol(mydata)
  {

    mydata[i,j]<- ifelse(mydata[i,j]==0 ,0 ,mydata[i,1])
  }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But the dataset is actually very big and I am looking for a more vectorised / r way of doing this. Also in your solution wouldn't the first column data be replaced as well ? I need the first column to stay intact.

Comment: And it should be mydata[i,1] instead of mydata[1,j] in the end of the ifelse if I am not mistaken

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. It's mainly because of multitasking at this moment :) Hope by the new changes your second problem is solved. I agree that this is not the most efficient way to solve this problem. I'm interested in seeing others answers to see how they approach this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your data frame is `dat`, I have a **fully-vectorized** solution for you:

```
mat <- as.matrix(dat[, -1])
pos <- which(mat != 0)
mat[pos] <- rep(dat[[1]], times = ncol(mat))[pos]
new_dat <- "colnames<-"(cbind.data.frame(dat[1], mat), colnames(dat))
```

---

**Example**

```
set.seed(0)
dat <- "colnames<-"(cbind.data.frame(1:5, matrix(sample(0:1, 25, TRUE), 5)),
                    c("val", letters[1:5]))
#  val a b c d e
#1   1 1 0 0 1 1
#2   2 0 1 0 0 1
#3   3 0 1 0 1 0
#4   4 1 1 1 1 1
#5   5 1 1 0 0 0
```

My code above gives:

```
#  val a b c d e
#1   1 1 0 0 1 1
#2   2 0 2 0 0 2
#3   3 0 3 0 3 0
#4   4 4 4 4 4 4
#5   5 5 5 0 0 0
```

---

**You want a benchmark?**

```
set.seed(0)
n <- 2000  ## use a 2000 * 2000 matrix
dat <- "colnames<-"(cbind.data.frame(1:n, matrix(sample(0:1, n * n, TRUE), n)),
                    c("val", paste0("x",1:n)))

## have to test my solution first, as aichao's solution overwrites `dat`

## my solution
system.time({mat <- as.matrix(dat[, -1])
            pos <- which(mat != 0)
            mat[pos] <- rep(dat[[1]], times = ncol(mat))[pos]
            "colnames<-"(cbind.data.frame(dat[1], mat), colnames(dat))})
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.352   0.056   0.410 

## solution by aichao
system.time(dat[,-1] <- sapply(dat[,-1], function(x) {ind <- which(x!=0); x[ind] = dat[ind,1]; x}))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  7.804   0.108   7.919
```

My solution is 20 times faster!

Comment: Didn't try to reproduce and understand your code yet but results are not what I want. I want non-zeros to be given the value of the first number in each row, your solution changes zeros to the first number

Comment: I accept a solution that is easy for me to understand and @aichao was kind enough to provide a thorough explanation for the workings of his code. To me as a beginner it is more important than having the absolute best performance, this is not a race to the end, but an exercise in learning more about r.